# Limit Shipping to specific countries

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping, shipping-address, countries

I have two Sites one for GBP and one for Euro.

For the Euro version I have set:

```
Stores > Configuration > General > General > 'Default Country' = 'Ireland'
Stores > Configuration > General > General > 'Allow Countries' = 'Ireland'
Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > 'Ship to Applicable Countries' = 'Specific Countries'
Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > 'Ship to Specific Countries' = 'Ireland'
```

And for the UK I have set:

```
Stores > Configuration > General > General > 'Default Country' = 'United Kingdom'
Stores > Configuration > General > General > 'Allow Countries' = 'United Kingdom'
Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > 'Ship to Applicable Countries' = 'Specific Countries'
Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > 'Ship to Specific Countries' = 'United Kingdom'
```

My default config for both Sites is:

```
Stores > Configuration > General > General > 'Default Country' = 'Ireland'
Stores > Configuration > General > General > 'Allow Countries' = 'Ireland'
Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > 'Ship to Applicable Countries' = 'Specific Countries'
Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > 'Ship to Specific Countries' = 'Null'
```

I have it set up to allow customer accounts globally so someone can create an account on one Site and have a saved address in one country but if they are accessing the Site for the other country they shouldn't see the saved addresses for the other Site.

However when I go to the Cart or Checkout the dropdown menu includes both countries for both Sites. Any ideas how I can change this so that there is no drop down for the country but that the correct country for the correct Site is shown by default?

Cart Summary:

[image]

Checkout:

[image]

I am using Magento 2.1.11

Comment: I have the correct countries selected by default but they have the option to change it, I tried just hiding these options so the default country is automatically selected but if someone had entered the country on the other site before and they have cached items to auto-fill the form it will change the hidden field as well

Comment: Is there any way to change the customer address form so that only the correct country is selected and it cannot be changed or loaded into form autofill data from the cache